Why is this matrix exactly singular? Trying to create my own contrast matrix but don't understand the error
I have six conditions. We can call them A, B, C, D, E, F.
I am trying to create a contrast matrix in R. I will use these contrasts in a regression model.
#Compare A, B, C to D, E, F
contrast1 <- c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3,  -1/3, -1/3, -1/3)
#Next compare A and D to C and F.
contrast2 <- c(1/2, 0, -1/2, 1/2, 0, -1/2) 
#Next compare B and E to C and F
contrast3 <- c(0, 1/2, -1/2, 0, 1/2, -1/2) 
#Next compare A and D to B and E
contrast4 <- c(1/2, -1/2, 0, 1/2, -1/2, 0) 
#Create interaction
contrast.interaction <- contrast1 * contrast4

mat.temp <- rbind(constant=1/6, contrast1, contrast2, contrast3, contrast4, contrast.interaction)
mat.temp

Here is the output of the matrix:
                          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
constant             0.1666667  0.1666667  0.1666667  0.1666667  0.1666667  0.1666667
contrast1            0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333 -0.3333333 -0.3333333 -0.3333333
contrast2            0.5000000  0.0000000 -0.5000000  0.5000000  0.0000000 -0.5000000
contrast3            0.0000000  0.5000000 -0.5000000  0.0000000  0.5000000 -0.5000000
contrast4            0.5000000 -0.5000000  0.0000000  0.5000000 -0.5000000  0.0000000
contrast.interaction 0.1666667 -0.1666667  0.0000000 -0.1666667  0.1666667  0.0000000

When I run solve() as in:
mat <- solve(mat.temp)

The error I get is:

Error in solve.default(mat.temp) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[6,6] = 0

So I understand it is singular, but I do not understand how/why? Which contrast(s) contribute to this problem?

If you showed us the array of values in mat.temp it would be easier to answer your question. It is basically telling you that one line of your matrix can be expressed as a linear sum of the others.  c4 == c2 - c3 so you are dead in the water.

If the columns are A,B,C,D,E,F then A+B-2C = D+E-2F so they are linearly dependent.

Another way to see this is to form the symmetric block matrix
M<-18*tcrossprod(mat.temp); dimnames(M)<-list(LETTERS[1:6],LETTERS[1:6]);  M
Now mat.temp is singular iff M is but M is block diagonal so we can inspect the three blocks and if any is singular then mat.temp is. In particular the C,D,E block is  singular as C=D+E so max.temp is singular.

All of them. Here's a linear combination of your columns that sums to a zero vector:
v <- c(1, 1, -2, -1, -1, 2)
c(mat.temp %*% v)
## [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

How I figured this out:

run caret::findLinearCombos(mat.temp) (identifies that all 6 of the columns are simultaneously collinear - i.e., there's no subset that would be collinear by itself)
use eigen(mat.temp). In particular if ee <- eigen(mat.temp) then v <- ee$vectors[,6]/sqrt(1/12) gives us the linear combination used above (the 1/sqrt(12) isn't strictly necessary but makes things prettier).

@G.Grothendieck's comment:

If the columns are A,B,C,D,E,F then A+B-2C = D+E-2F so they are linearly dependent

is equivalent (but requires you to just stare at the columns to figure it out rather than just computing ...)
